# Dar formato de rut en TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando en una app la cual contiene un formulario de **Login** (rut y pass), me piden que al momento de ir ingresando valores en el campo de rut este le entregue el formato instantáneamente, por ejemplo: **xx.xxx.xxx-x**.

Me pueden dar alguna sugerencia de como poder hacerlo.

Actualizo mi pregunta.

en el onCreate de la clase Login, hago el llamado a la clase MaskWatcher,

```
login.addTextChangedListener(new MaskWatcher(login.toString()));
```

en esta clase realizo una validación para llamar a una función que me entrega el rut formateado.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    Log.i("MaskWatcher","Valor Editable"+editable);


    String valortext = editable.toString();
    Log.i("MaskWatcher","Valor valortext"+valortext);
    if(valortext.equals(""))
    {
        Log.i("MaskWatcher","Valor valortext 0"+valortext);
        valortext = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("MaskWatcher","Valor valortext !0"+valortext);
        valortext = FormatearRUT(valortext);
    }
}
public  String FormatearRUT(String rut) {

    Log.i("MaskWatcher","FormatearRUT valor"+rut);
    int cont = 0;
    String format;
    rut = rut.replace(".", "");
    rut = rut.replace("-", "");
    format = "-" + rut.substring(rut.length() - 1);
    for (int i = rut.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        format = rut.substring(i, i + 1) + format;
        cont++;
        if (cont == 3 && i != 0) {
            format = "." + format;
            cont = 0;
        }
    }
    Log.i("MaskWatcher","FormatearRUT valorformat"+format);


    return format;
}
```

y es acá en donde me complica un poco, porque necesito imprimir el valor de format en el edittext que está en la otra clase, la clase Login. Cómo podría realizar esto?

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien lo que significa formato xx.xxx.xxx-x pero una solucion para dar formato a la entrada de texto en un edittext podria ser:

```
 tueditext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tueditext);
 tueditext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String valortext = tueditext.getText().toString().trim();
            if(valortext.equals(""))
                {
                valortext = "0";
                }
            Formatear tu valortext con el formato que quieras.
            }
    });
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Pero que formato realizaría esta solución a la entrada de un texto en un EditText?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esta función que formatea el rut ingresado al formato que necesitas:

```
    public String FormatearRUT(String rut) {
            int cont = 0;
            String format;
            rut = rut.replace(".", "");
            rut = rut.replace("-", "");
            format = "-" + rut.substring(rut.length() - 1);
            for (int i = rut.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                format = rut.substring(i, i + 1) + format;
                cont++;
                if (cont == 3 && i != 0) {
                    format = "." + format;
                    cont = 0;
                }
            }
            return format;
    }
   //Tomado de la primera respuesta 
    tueditext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tueditext);
    tueditext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    String valortext = tueditext.getText().toString().trim();
                    if(valortext.equals(""))
                        {
                        valortext = "0";
                        }
                    else
                    {
                      valortext = FormatearRUT(valortext); //Sustituyes por la funcion que te formateara el rut
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: estimado muchas gracias por su respuesta, pero como puedo ir dando formato al momento de ir ingresando valores en el campo de texto?

Comment: hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió mucho pero ahora tengo otro problema, voy a actualizar mi pregunta para detallar el problema

Answer (score 0):

Si el rut es un numerico podrias utilizar `DecimalFormat`

Ejemplo

```
editRut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editRut);
 editRut.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String valortext = tueditext.getText().toString().trim();
            if(valortext.equals(""))
                {
                valortext = "0";
                }
           DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("xx.xxx.xxx-x");
           editRut.setText(formater.format(Double.parseDouble(s)));
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera se da formato a medida que se introduce el rut por parte del usuario.

```
public String formatearRUT(String rut) { //funcion levemente modificada de la respuesta anterior
            String format;
            int cont = 0;
            rut = rut.replace(".", "");
            rut = rut.replace("-", "");
            if ((rut.length() - 1) != 0) {
                format = "-" + rut.substring(rut.length() - 1);
                for (int i = rut.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                    format = rut.charAt(i) + format;
                    cont++;
                    if (cont == 3 && i != 0) {
                        format = "." + format;
                        cont = 0;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return rut;
            }
            return format;
}
```

La funcion se ejecuta cada vez que se agrega un caracter.

```
rutED = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rutED);
        rutED.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            private boolean isEditing = false;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String rut = String.valueOf(rutED.getText());
                if (!isEditing && !rut.isEmpty()) {
                    isEditing = true;
                    rutED.getText().clear();
                    rutED.append(formatearRUT(rut));
                    isEditing = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
```